# Can't use Get in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, get, myspace

So I'm using codeigniter and I've had very letter experience with it so far but here's my issue.

I have an if statement I've set up that says if (@$_GET['f'] == 'callback') then do something, if not, do something else.

So basically my URL ends up looking like this:

http://localhost/finalproject/myspacedev/index?f=start

and all I get is a 404 page. I've tried turning on get in the config, done a bunch of reading on here about using the uri segment class in CI, but all I get are 404 errors. What am I doing wrong here? It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I'm dumb.

It's PATH_INFO, not PATH INFO.

Still having some issues but for now I'm good.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter automatically maps `$_GET` variables to class member parameters, which is far nicer to work with (see [Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) in the CI docs).

An example:

```
<?php
class blog extends Controller {

    function archives($filter = '') {
        // $filter is a $_GET paramemter
    }
}
?>
```

The above controller would be available at `/blog/archives/` and anything after that portion of the URI would be passed as the `$_GET` parameters.  If `/blog/archives/` returns a 404, then you probably don't have the `.htaccess` file in the web root, or you may not have it enabled in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It must have something to do with my .htaccess file, even though I thought I had it set up correctly. I tried to do it that way and never had any success so I just ended up enabling GET with the parse_str line that everyone passes around.

In any case, I got it to work even if its not the cleanest, most efficient way.